# regex (Javascript) allow comma to be ignore

Tags: javascript, regex

```
const value = 'I am a student. My age is 5';
const regex = new RegExp('\\b' + value, 'i'); //what to add here?

console.log(regex.test('I am a student, my age is 5')); //true
console.log(regex.test('I am a student my age is 5')); //false
```

I want to ignore the `,` to make my second string to true.

Comment: Change `.` to `\\W?`

Comment: I want to ignore it, not make it unmatch.

Comment: You can't ignore anything when it comes to regex. You either match or avoid matching some text using the regex pattern (adjusting it.)

Answer (score -1):

you probably want a more generic regex like this:

```js
const regex =  /^I am a \w+[.,]? My age is \d+$/i

console.log(regex.test('I am a student, my age is 5')); //should be true
console.log(regex.test('I am a student my age is 5')); //should be true
console.log(regex.test('I am a INSERTWORD my age is 5')); //should be true
console.log(regex.test('I am a student my age is 230')); //should be true
```

a less genric regex could look like this:

```js
const regex =  /^I am a student[.,]? My age is 5$/i

console.log(regex.test('I am a student, my age is 5')); //should be true
console.log(regex.test('I am a student my age is 5')); //should be true
console.log(regex.test('I am a INSERTWORD my age is 5')); //should be false
console.log(regex.test('I am a student my age is 230')); //should be false
```

if you want to learn more about regexes go to one of:

https://regex101.com/ regex 101 is my go to regex testing website.

https://www.regextester.com/

https://regexr.com/

Comment: I have already suggested the same approach with a more generic pattern, [OP says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59101061/regex-javascript-allow-comma-to-be-ignore#comment104434804_59101061) it is not what is necessary.

Comment: its faster, you only create regexes from variables when you don't have an alternative.